# Generate DDL script for MySQL in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, mysql-workbench, ddl

I made a relational model in Oracle SQL Developer and I want to make tables in MySQL Workbench. I generated the DDL script in SQL Developer and copied it in MySQL Workbench. I found out that the copied queries are not in correct syntax. I tried different options in SQL Developer to generate script and none of them were in MySQL syntax.

Is there a way to generate DDL script from a model, which is made in SQL Developer, for MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight query generation for MySQL in oracle SQL developer. You should use such a  [sites](https://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql) for your purpose to convert them into MySQL syntax or use tools for automatic converting.